# Looking for a comfortable DTC endgame database

Tags: endgame, tablebases

The only online endgame database supporting DTC (Depth To Conversion) that I know of is [jaet](http://chess.jaet.org/cgi-bin/mzugs).

Unfortunately for me, the positions can only be entered by FEN. It is not possible to drag pieces, as I would prefer. Being able to drag the pieces around would be comfortable for me.

- Does anyone know a comfortable online endgame database supporting DTC, i.e. you can drag the pieces around?
- Does anyone know where I can download DTC-supporting files ? 
  (I only have downloaded the Nalimov files, which only support DTM)

Comment: What difference is between DTC and DTZ used in syzygy? What is 'conversion'?

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive Googling, it appears to me that the the DTC tablebase named [jaet](http://chess.jaet.org/endings/) that you linked is the only one that is online currently. As such, there may not exist "click and drag" DTC tablebases out there.

However, if you are still adamant about using a "drag" feature, you're best bet is to use the [Lichess board editor](https://lichess.org/editor) to create your position, and then copy paste the FEN into jaet.

I'll demonstrate this easy process using some pictures for the benefit of any who do not understand how to do the above mentioned process. Some people are visual learners, so you never know.

1. Go the [Lichess board editor](https://lichess.org/editor).
   [image]
2. Use the "drag" feature to create your position.
   [image]
3. Copy the FEN.
   [image]
4. Paste the FEN into the right bar at the [jaet site](http://chess.jaet.org/endings/)
   [image]
5. Click the "Lookup FEN" button that's next to the FEN bar and check the results.
   [image]